# TEA implemention in VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am wondering if anyone is able to help with converting some code from C++ to vb.net.

I have been given the code to implement within VB but I have having some issues when passing through values in that the code stops as the number value increases past the allowed limit for the type.

The original code is below:

```
void decrypt(unsigned char* v, unsigned long* k)
{
unsigned long v0, v1, sum=0x########, i; /* set up */
unsigned long delta=0x######; /* a key schedule constant */
unsigned long k0=k[0], k1=k[1], k2=k[2], k3=k[3]; /* cache key */
// MAKE UNSIGNED LONG VALUES FROM PASSED CHARACTER BUFFER
v0 = (unsigned long)v[0] |
(unsigned long)v[1] << 8 |
(unsigned long)v[2] << 16 |
(unsigned long)v[3] << 24;
v1 = (unsigned long)v[4] |
(unsigned long)v[5] << 8 |
(unsigned long)v[6] << 16 |
(unsigned long)v[7] << 24;
for (i=0; i<32; i++) { /* basic cycle start */
v1 -= ((v0<<4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>5) + k3);
v0 -= ((v1<<4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>5) + k1);
sum -= delta;
} /* end cycle */
// WRITE THE DATA BACK TO THE CHARACTER ARRAY
v[0] = (unsigned char)(v0);
v[1] = (unsigned char)(v0 >> 8);
v[2] = (unsigned char)(v0 >> 16);
v[3] = (unsigned char)(v0 >> 24);
v[4] = (unsigned char)(v1);
v[5] = (unsigned char)(v1 >> 8);
v[6] = (unsigned char)(v1 >> 16);
v[7] = (unsigned char)(v1 >> 24);
}
```

My vb code is below:

```
Private Sub Decrypt()
    Try
        Dim v0, v1, sum, delta As Long
        v0 = 0
        v1 = 0
        Dim i As Integer
        sum = &#######
        delta = &#######
        Dim k0 As ULong = k(0)
        Dim k1 As ULong = k(1)
        Dim k2 As ULong = k(2)
        Dim k3 As ULong = k(3)
        Debug.Print(v(0) & " " & v(1) & " " & v(2) & " " & v(3) & " " & v(4) & " " & v(5) & " " & v(6) & " " & v(7))
        ' MAKE UNSIGNED LONG VALUES FROM PASSED CHARACTER BUFFER
        v0 = v(0) Or (v(1) << 8) Or (v(2) << 16) Or (v(3) << 24)
        v1 = v(4) Or (v(5) << 8) Or (v(6) << 16) Or (v(7) << 24)
        For i = 1 To 32
            Debug.Print(((v0 << 4) + k2))
            Debug.Print((v0 + sum))
            Debug.Print(((v0 >> 5) + k3))
            v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) Xor (v0 + sum) Xor ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
            v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) Xor (v1 + sum) Xor ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
            sum -= delta
        Next
        ' WRITE THE DATA BACK TO THE CHARACTER ARRAY
        v(0) = v0
        v(1) = v0 >> 8
        v(2) = v0 >> 16
        v(3) = v0 >> 24
        v(4) = v1
        v(5) = v1 >> 8
        v(6) = v1 >> 16
        v(7) = v1 >> 24
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("TEA_Encription - Decrypt " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I load my key values into the constant K(0 to 4) and then 8 16 bit integers into the values v(0 to 7)

The code is failing on the lines

```
v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) Xor (v0 + sum) Xor ((v0 >> 5) + k3)
v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) Xor (v1 + sum) Xor ((v1 >> 5) + k1)
```

around the 4th iteration of the loop.

Any pointers please would be greatfully received

Comment: You may need to do this in C# (in an `unchecked` block).  I rather suspect that you need wrap-around overflow behavior, but VB (and "checked" C#) will trap on integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The original code is using unsigned long throughout.  But you're using signed long variables in part.

Try changing

```
Dim v0, v1, sum, delta As Long
```

To

```
Dim v0, v1, sum, delta As ULong
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I originally had the values above as ULong data types but the code still fails - earlier though! It fails on the first line v1 as the result becomes negative and the uLong data type does not support negative numbers.